# Ubuntu won't boot after deleting a partition

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have a laptop that I run 2 OSs on, Ubuntu and Chromium. They are on separate hard drives, and I physically swap the drives when I want to change the OS.

Recently I wanted to install Windows 7 instead of Chromium, so I went ahead and began installing Windows. I got to the screen where you select the disk/partition to install to, and I started deleting the old partitions. That's when I realized that I had forgotten to switch the drives, and I was deleting Ubuntu partitions. I only deleted one, it was the smaller partition (~200MB). I think this was the boot partition because now Ubuntu won't boot. How can I get this partition back?

Comment: How did you set it up to begin with?  Normally there is one partition for swap, which should be a few gb, and one for everything else.

Comment: I just installed it directly from the live USB, no changes made. I don't think it was swap space as its now showing only a few hundred meg unallocated on the drive and that seems a bit small for swap.

Comment: If you didn't choose manual partitioning, then you don't get a /boot partition, so your description doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), which comes on most Linux emergency discs and live CDs.

Given the size of the partition, I suspect this may have been an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which is a FAT partition that holds EFI boot loaders. If I'm right, you'll need to give it an appropriate type code after you restore it. You can do this with `gdisk`, `sgdisk`, or `cgdisk` by setting the type code to EF00; or with `parted` or GParted by setting the "boot flag" on the partition. If this is *not* an ESP, though, you may not want to run `gdisk`, `sgdisk`, or `cgdisk` on the disk, and you might or might not want to set the "boot flag" with `parted` or GParted.

Comment: ok, how would I be able to tell if it was an ESP?

Comment: OK, I tried using test disk, but I couldn't get it to do anything.

Theres only a few files on there that I want to save, I tried copying them onto a removable hard drive using the live USB, but The files are in my home directory and I don't have permission to read them, how can I get around this?

Comment: Given your description, I think you used PhotoRec, not TestDisk. TestDisk recovers entire partitions, not individual files.

Comment: Sorry, I worded that badly, I tried using testdisk, gave up and then tried to copy the files using the standard file manager.

Comment: OK, ive got the files I need now, I had to use chmod to change the file permissions. Thanks for the help!